# Consistent estimate using likelihood function

Tags: statistics

Let be $X$ a population with normal distribution. Using likelihood function I get the below expression 
$\hat{\sigma_X}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{\dfrac{(X_i-\mu)^2}{n}}$
for variance.

I want prove that expression is consistent, i.e. $E[\hat{\sigma_X}^2]=\sigma_X^2$.

I begin ...

$E[\hat{\sigma_X}^2]=\dfrac{1}{n}E[\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(X_i-\mu)^2}]$

$\dfrac{1}{n}(E[(X_1-\mu)^2]+E[(X_2-\mu)^2]\cdots E[(X_n-\mu)^2])$

I don't know what else to do.

pdta: $\mu=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}{X_i}$

Comment: Do you intend the parameter $\mu$ to be a fixed constant, of a random variable, function of $X_i$?

Comment: yes, $\mu=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}{X_i}$

Comment: In that case, it is a well known result that $\mathsf{E}\left(\hat{\sigma}_X^2\right) = \frac{n-1}{n} \sigma_X^2$.

Comment: but, in mi lecture would have to be $E[\hat{\sigma_X}^2] = \sigma_X^2$ and not $\mathsf{E}\left(\hat{\sigma}_X^2\right) = \frac{n-1}{n} \sigma_X^2$...(for the consistent)... then this estimative is not consistent?

Comment: The proper term is $\hat{\sigma}_X^2$ is a biased estimator. Consistency has to do with large $n$ limit. $\hat{\sigma}_X^2$ is consistent, since the expectation approaches the population value for large $n$.

Comment: but then is not biased, because $E[\hat{\sigma_X}^2]$ is not equal to $\sigma_X^2$ ... or not?

Comment: sorry, now understand, please will be able to development this expression $\mathsf{E}\left(\hat{\sigma}_X^2\right) = \frac{n-1}{n} \sigma_X^2$... What steps remain? ...

Answer (score 0):

To show the desired (weak) consistency, you have to show that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \mu)^2$ converges in probability to $\sigma^2$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

To that end, note that
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \mu)^2
= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 
- 2 \cdot \mu \cdot  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n  X_i
+ \mu^2.
$$
Assuming $X_i \overset{\mathrm{i.i.d.}}{\sim} \mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ for $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$, the [weak law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Weak_law) gives
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \overset{p}{\underset{n \to \infty}\longrightarrow} \mathbb E[X_1]\;\; \text{and} \,\;
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \overset{p}{\underset{n \to \infty}\longrightarrow} \mathbb E[X_1^2].
$$
With $\mathbb E[X_1] = \mu$, the [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem#Statement) yields
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 
- 2 \cdot \mu \cdot  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n  X_i
+ \mu^2 \overset{p}{\underset{n \to \infty}\longrightarrow} 
\mathbb E[X_1^2] - 2 \cdot (\mathbb E[X_1])^2 + (\mathbb E[X_1])^2.
$$
Finally, $\mathbb E[X_1^2] - 2 \cdot (\mathbb E[X_1])^2 + (\mathbb E[X_1])^2 = \mathbb E[X_1^2] - (\mathbb E[X_1])^2 = \mathbb V[X_1] = \sigma^2.$

---

Strong consistency follows analogously by using the [strong law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law) and replacing convergence in probability by almost sure convergence.